# I want to ignore statusbarstyle in overlay window

Tags: ios, uiwindow, uistatusbar

I have a window(A) with rootviewcontroller and will make another window(B) with other rootviewcontroller.
Window A is keyWindow, but I will overlay window B on window A. windowB is transparent.

When window B overlay on windowA, app's `statusBarStyle` is driven by window B! Not window A!
I wanna ignore window B's rootviewcontroller's `statusBarStyle`.
I wanna adjust statusbar style by window A.

I'm using `prefersstatusbarstyle` to set `statusBarstyle`.
Because my `Info.plist`'s View controller-based status bar `appearance : YES.` (`UIApplication setStatusBarStyle` is deprecated).

How can I do this?

Comment: `setStatusBarStyle ` is deprecated, but `statusBarStyle` is not. So use it.

Comment: @AuRis thanks for answering. but in apple documents, [statusBarStyle is deprecated.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622988-statusbarstyle?language=objc)